# redirect old url to new url

Tags: .htaccess

I am facing a problem in redirecting a old url to a new one.

This is the old url: `http://www.abc.com/department.asp?dept=Minimal%20cloth`

the new url should be: `http://www.abc.com/Minimal-cloth`

Please suggest me the best possible way

Comment: do you whant to do this in a webpage redirect or using server side redirect?

Comment: Hi,I don't want to use it in a webpage or using any server side redirect....I want to use .htaccess..

Answer (score 1):

Can you try following rules in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# to take care of /department.asp?dept=Minimal%20cloth or 
# /department.asp?dept=Minimal cloth tyoe of URLs
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^dept=(.+)(\s|%20)(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^department\.asp$ /%1-%3? [R=302,L,NC]

# to take care of /department.asp?dept=MinimalCloth type URLs 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^dept=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^department\.asp$ /%1? [R=302,L,NC]
```

Remember RewriteRule doesn't match query string.

Comment: Hi Anubhava,sorry to reply late.I tried with it but again it takes me to the 404 page...Is there anything with the %20

Comment: Hi Anubhava....the code is working well sorry my mistake,I missed an operator.But its not what I am trying to do...Is it not possible to use mod alias i mean using 301 redirect.I have to redirect one by one suppose a category from old site which doesn't exist in new site so in that case it will not find and send me to 404 but at a same time I want to redirect that old category in a new one.I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Actually if you make a minor change to have rewrite rule like this: `RewriteRule ^.+\.asp$ /%1-%3? [R=302,L,NC]` then you don't need to have a rule for each category.

Answer (score 0):

Apache's mod_rewrite is perfect for this. [Excellent tutorial here](http://www.easymodrewrite.com/).

Comment: Hi..thanks...ya I have gone through that tutorial but no luck :(

Comment: Well, I don't know what you expect me to suggest, because and mod_rewrite is how you would do this if you wanted to use .htaccess. Either mod_rewrite does not work on your server or you are doing something incorrectly. Either way, mod_rewrite DOES work and is in use on hundreds of thousands of websites all around the world. So ya, read the tutorial again.

Comment: mod_rewrite is working in my server and I was trying to use something like this 

Redirect 301 "/department.asp?dept=Minimal/ expense/" http://www.abc.com/Minimal-expense

How can I achieve this using htaccess

Comment: That isn't mod_rewrite. The module uses RedirectRule and RedirectCond directives in the .htaccess file, so I don't think you have read and followed the tutorial (it's on the third page, btw :).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which modules are enabled in the apache server's config, you can use either mod_alias or mod_rewrite for this. To use mod_alias, use something like

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/department\.asp\?dept=(.*) /$1
```

To use mod_rewrite try something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^dept=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/department\.asp/%1 [R=301]
```

These haven't been tested, but hope they get you started.

Comment: RewriteRule doesn't match query string only REQUEST_URI is matched.

Comment: oops, thanks @anubhava, forgot that RewriteRule doesn't look at query string....I updated my answer

Comment: Hi Dave...sorry to reply late....I have tried this one too but same as before...its taking me to 404